Arduino float equation returning inf due to division of 0
So my problem is very similar to this issue posted many years ago but I don't see where the solution was, therefore I am asking again because I cannot seem to solve this issue.
text
Below is part of my main code that I was able to pinpoint where INF was coming from. I have found that the denominator is a zero when this runs and prints. But my question is how is it calculating a zero as the denominator? If I take the same values and do it by hand or in an excel sheet, I don't get a zero.
float x = 66920.05469;
float y = -0.76569;
float xy = -840.00122;
float xSq = 73414648.00;
float ySq = 0.01022;
float nReadings = 61.00;
float times = 1097.05249;

Serial << "x: " << x << endl;
Serial << "y: " << y << endl;
Serial << "xy: " << xy << endl;
Serial << "xSq: " << xSq << endl;
Serial << "ySq: " << ySq << endl;
Serial << "nReadings: " << nReadings << endl;

float denominator = (nReadings * xSq) - (x * x);
Serial << "denominator: " << denominator << endl;

float numerator = (nReadings * xy) - (x * y);
Serial << "numerator: " << numerator << endl;

float slope = (numerator) / (denominator);
float b = (y - slope * x) / nReadings;

Serial.print("Slope, m: ");
Serial.println(slope, 5);

Serial.print("y-int, b: ");
Serial.println(b, 5);

int middle_index_z = nReadings / 2;
Serial.print("Middle time (x): ");

Serial.println(times, 5);
value = slope * times + b;
Serial << "value: " << value << endl;
Serial << endl;

Side Note: If I change the nReadings = 61.00 to nReadings = 61.00001 it doesn't result in an INF anymore. But I assigned it as a float though when it was 61.00?

Can you make this a [mcve], and also post the complete output?

To save us some time in checking calculations, what do you expect denominator to equal? Is it very close to 0?

Check float denominator = (nReadings * xSq) - (x * x); and you'll probably find that denominator becomes zero which makes float slope = (numerator) / (denominator); into a division by zero.

x*x is 4478293719.7125909961 nReadings * xSq is 4478293528 if you put the first number into https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html you'll find that the nearest representation of it as a float is 4478293504 so you might expect that you'll get a non-zero result but 4478293528 is also not representable as a float and is rounded to 4478293504 giving you a final result of 0

https://godbolt.org/z/GhTdhYKcx

Changing all the float variables to double fixes this problem.

@john that's almost always a bad idea on such tiny embedded MCUs. Fixed point operations are much better
